# How to send div element using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to send a section of html content (not a form data) through AJAX.
I know how to do this in jQuery but i want to achieve with javascript.

**HTML** (I want to send content who has id=stack)
after clicking on SEND button button, response must be loaded in id=target

```
<div id='stack'>
    <ol>
        <li>stack 1</li>
        <li>stack 2</li>
        <li>stack 3</li>
    </ol>
</div>

<button id='btn'>SEND</button>
<article id='target'></article>
```

**AJAX**

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var target = document.getElementById('target');

    // Function for AJAX
    function stack(){
    var main = document.getElementById('stack');
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "process.php", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState ==4 && xhr.status == 200){
            target.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.send(main);
    }

    // Bind with the onclick event
    btn.addEventListener('click',stack,false);
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
$div = $_POST;
print_r($div);
?>
```

> After running my above code it is just displaying **Array()**
>   because Ajax method is not sending the div.

**Please help me using Javascript instead of jQuery**

Comment: is `$div` must be an array?

Comment: @Shizukura no. It's not neccessary to be an array. I used $_POST to check what it will receive. But it is not receiving any data.

Answer (score 0):

Do not send the element reference itself, get the `outerHTML` property and send that one like so: `xhr.send(main.outerHTML);`

This sends a string version of the element including its descendants.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

Comment: If it can be done by using main.outerHTML then please tell me how to access it in process.php because $_POST is still returning empty Array().

Answer (score 0):

okay guys !
I asked the above question and finally successfully solved my problem.
So I am going to share my solution with you (love).
**SOLUTION :**

---

**AJAX**
There is one line of code i missed in ajax.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

So the full Ajax code will be -

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var target = document.getElementById('target');

    // Function for AJAX
    function stack(){
    var main = document.getElementById('stack');
    //*****new line added
    var data = 'key' + '=' + main.outerHTML; 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "process.php", true);
    //*****(new line added) must add when working with POST data
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState ==4 && xhr.status == 200){
            target.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.send(data);
    }

    // Bind with the onclick event
    btn.addEventListener('click',stack,false);
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
$div = $_POST;

echo $div['key'];
?>
```

<kbd>**Thank You !**</kbd>